# An ellipsoid intersects with a plane passing through the origin.

Tags: calculus, geometry, solid-geometry

Ellipsoid $E:\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$, and plane $P:lx + my + nz = 0$.

Assuming that the intersection of $E$ and $P$ is denoted as $D$, and the coordinates of the point d on D are represented as  $(x, y, z) = (p, q, r)$. Find the maximum of $p$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, you are encouraged to provide more details about your problem, and especially your effort to solve it.  Problems without sufficient context are poorly received on this website, and the community is directed by the website policies not to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

First, transform the ellipsoid into a sphere, be defining

$u = \dfrac{x}{a}, v = \dfrac{y}{b} , w = \dfrac{z}{c} $

Now we have the ellipsoid transformed into the unit sphere

$ u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1 $

Apply the same transformation to the plane, its equation in terms of $u, v, w$ becomes

$ a l \ u + b m \ v + c n \ w = 0 $

Let $N = ( a l , b m , c n ) $

The intersection of the plane and unit sphere is a circle with radius $1$, and a normal vector that is equal to $N$.  Now let $r$ be define as

$ r = \sqrt{ (al)^2 + (bm)^2 + (cn)^2 } $

Then the unit vector along $N$ is

$ \hat{n} = \dfrac{N}{r} $

Further, $\hat{n}$ can be parameterized in spherical coordinates as follows

$ \hat{n} = ( \sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta) $

Associated with $\hat{n}$ are two standard unit vectors that orthogonal to it, they are

$ u_1 = ( \cos \theta \cos \phi, \cos \theta \sin \phi, - \sin \theta )$

$ u_2 = ( - \sin \phi, \cos \phi , 0 ) $

The equation of the circle of intersection between the unit sphere and the plane is

$(u, v, w) = \cos(t) u_1 + \sin(t) u_2 $

Thus,

$(u,v,w) = ( \cos(t) \cos \theta \cos \phi - \sin(t) \sin \phi, \cos(t) \cos \theta \sin \phi + \sin(t) \cos \phi, - \cos(t) \sin \theta ) $

Now $x = a u  = a (\cos(t) \cos \theta \cos \phi - \sin(t) \sin \phi ) $

The maximum of $x$ is given by

$ x_{Max} = a \sqrt{ \cos^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi } $

$          = a \sqrt{ 1 - \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi } $

Using the above relation between $N$ and $\theta$ and $\phi$ we obtain,

$ \sin^2 \theta = \dfrac{ (al)^2 + (bm)^2 }{ (al)^2 + (bm)^2 + (c n)^2 }$

Therefore,

$ tan \phi = \dfrac{ b m }{a l }  $

Hence,

$ cos^2 \phi = \dfrac{ 1 }{1 + tan^2 \phi } = \dfrac{ (al)^2 }{ (al)^2 + (bm)^2 }$

Therefore,

$ x_{Max} = a \sqrt{ 1 - \dfrac{ (al)^2 }{ ( (al)^2 + (bm)^2 + (cn)^2 ) }}$

which can also written as,

$ x_{Max} = a \sqrt{ \dfrac{(bm)^2 + (cn)^2 }{ (al)^2 + (bm)^2 + (cn)^2 }}$